# Error while loading reading loading csv file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to scala, and want to load a csv file. Please find my code below;

```
package rddbasics

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RddWithCsvFile {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Creating Rdd with CSV")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val csvRdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:\\data\\hr_db\\employees\\part-00000.csv")

    println(csvRdd.count)
  }
}
```

Maven is able to build the class, but while running its throwing the below exception

```
Error:scalac: Error while emitting RddWithCsvFile.scala
assertion failed: 
  Bad superClass for class Nothing$: <none>
     while compiling: C:\Documents\POC\scala\spark-maven-1\src\main\scala\rddbasics\RddWithCsvFile.scala
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.13.3
    compiler version: version 2.13.3
  reconstructed args: -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Documents\POC\scala\spark-maven-1\target\classes;C:\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.12.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\2.1.0\spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.11\0.8.0\chill_2.11-0.8.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo-shaded\3.0.3\kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\1.3.0\minlog-1.3.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.8.0\chill-java-0.8.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.2.0\hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.1\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.2.0\hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.2.0\hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.2.0\hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.11\2.1.0\spark-launcher_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.11\2.1.0\spark-network-common_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.5\jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.11\2.1.0\spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.11\2.1.0\spark-unsafe_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.7.1\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.4.0\curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.4.0\curator-framework-2.4.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.4.0\curator-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.4.1\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.16\slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.16\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.16\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar;C:\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.16\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2.6\snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\2.2\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.8\scala-library-2.11.8.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.11\3.2.11\json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.11.0\scalap-2.11.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.0\scala-compiler-2.11.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.22.2\jersey-client-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.4.0-b34\hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.4.0-b34\hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.4.0-b34\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.4.0-b34\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.4.0-b34\hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.22.2\jersey-common-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.22.2\jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-server\2.22.2\jersey-server-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.22.2\jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.22.2\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.42.Final\netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.8.0.Final\netty-3.8.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.5\jackson-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.11\2.6.5\jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.7\scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-paranamer\2.6.5\jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.13\pyrolite-4.13.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.10.4\py4j-0.10.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-tags_2.11\2.1.0\spark-tags_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scalatest\scalatest_2.11\2.2.6\scalatest_2.11-2.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-crypto\1.0.0\commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.11\2.1.0\spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\univocity\univocity-parsers\2.2.1\univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sketch_2.11\2.1.0\spark-sketch_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-catalyst_2.11\2.1.0\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\janino\3.0.0\janino-3.0.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler\3.0.0\commons-compiler-3.0.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.5.3\antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-column\1.8.1\parquet-column-1.8.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-common\1.8.1\parquet-common-1.8.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-encoding\1.8.1\parquet-encoding-1.8.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-hadoop\1.8.1\parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-format\2.3.0-incubating\parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-jackson\1.8.1\parquet-jackson-1.8.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-streaming_2.11\2.1.0\spark-streaming_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-hive_2.11\2.1.0\spark-hive_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\twitter\parquet-hadoop-bundle\1.6.0\parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\hive\hive-exec\1.2.1.spark2\hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javolution\javolution\5.5.1\javolution-5.5.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\log4j\apache-log4j-extras\1.2.17\apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.4\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\3.2.1\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\ST4\4.0.4\ST4-4.0.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\javaewah\JavaEWAH\0.3.2\JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\iq80\snappy\snappy\0.2\snappy-0.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\sf\opencsv\opencsv\2.3\opencsv-2.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\hive\hive-metastore\1.2.1.spark2\hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\jolbox\bonecp\0.8.0.RELEASE\bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derby\10.10.2.0\derby-10.10.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-api-jdo\3.2.6\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-rdbms\3.2.9\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\jdo\jdo-api\3.0.1\jdo-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.3\paranamer-2.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\calcite\calcite-avatica\1.2.0-incubating\calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\calcite\calcite-core\1.2.0-incubating\calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\calcite\calcite-linq4j\1.2.0-incubating\calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\hydromatic\eigenbase-properties\1.1.5\eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.2\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.4\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.3\joda-time-2.9.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-core\3.5.2\jodd-core-3.5.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-core\3.2.10\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\thrift\libthrift\0.9.2\libthrift-0.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\thrift\libfb303\0.9.2\libfb303-0.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-mllib_2.11\2.1.0\spark-mllib_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-graphx_2.11\2.1.0\spark-graphx_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\core\1.1.2\core-1.1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\f2j\arpack_combined_all\0.1\arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-mllib-local_2.11\2.1.0\spark-mllib-local_2.11-2.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scalanlp\breeze_2.11\0.12\breeze_2.11-0.12.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\scalanlp\breeze-macros_2.11\0.12\breeze-macros_2.11-0.12.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\github\rwl\jtransforms\2.4.0\jtransforms-2.4.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\spire-math\spire_2.11\0.7.4\spire_2.11-0.7.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\spire-math\spire-macros_2.11\0.7.4\spire-macros_2.11-0.7.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\chuusai\shapeless_2.11\2.0.0\shapeless_2.11-2.0.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jpmml\pmml-model\1.2.15\pmml-model-1.2.15.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jpmml\pmml-schema\1.2.15\pmml-schema-1.2.15.jar
  last tree to typer: Select(Ident(csvRdd), count)
       tree position: line 14 of C:\Documents\POC\scala\spark-maven-1\src\main\scala\rddbasics\RddWithCsvFile.scala
            tree tpe: (): Long
              symbol: method count in class RDD
   symbol definition: def count(): Long (a MethodSymbol)
      symbol package: org.apache.spark.rdd
       symbol owners: method count -> class RDD
           call site: constructor RddWithCsvFile in object RddWithCsvFile in package rddbasics
== Source file context for tree position ==
    11 
    12     val csvRdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:\\data\\hr_db\\employees\\part-00000.csv")
    13 
    14     println(csvRdd.count)
    15   }
    16 }
    17
```

I am not able to understand the issue, please help

Comment: can you share me the pom.xml here? so that we can investigate on it further.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read your csv file using following code :

```
val csvDataFrame = spark.read.csv("pathToFile/file.csv") // read the file
println(csvDataFrame.count()) //print the count
```